# String to Enumeration

Tags: matlab, enumeration

I have an enumerator:

```
classdef Commands

    properties
        commandString;
        readonly;
    end
    methods
        function obj = Commands(commandString, readonly)
            obj.commandString = commandString;
            obj.readonly= readonly;
        end
    end
    enumeration
        PositionMode('p', false)
        TravelDistance('s', false)
    end
end
```

and i have a string:

```
currentCommand = 'PositionMode';
```

I want to be able to return:

```
Commands.PositionMode
```

Is there any better solution than

```
methods(Static)
    function obj = str2Command(string)
        obj = eval(['Commands.' string]);
    end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As with structures, you can use [dynamic field names](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/13/use-dynamic-field-references/) with objects.

With

```
currentCommand = PositionMode
```

the call

```
Commands.(currentCommand)
```

evaluates to

```
Commands.PositionMode
```

and thus solves your problem in an elegant and convenient way.